# Using a Local Function over an Action as an input param

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I have a method that is taking in an `Action<string>` (see simple example below), but in the calling method where the `Action` is constructed, Resharper is suggesting that a Local Function should be used.

What are the recommended practices around using Local Functions in place of Actions, does it matter, or are there gotchas to be aware of?

```cs
public void Caller()
{
    string holder;
    Action<string> act = s => holder = s;
    void SetHolder(string s) => holder = s;

    DoStuff(act);
    DoStuff(SetHolder);
}

public void DoStuff(Action<string> setHolder)
{
    setHolder("holders new string");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking you code and putting it through [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACgoGYECY4DCcA3hnOQjlACyECGANgwKYBOAFAJQanoUKJ4ACwD2DYGzR8KSXAB4kMAHxw6AYwAucALxwAzjpWjxbHfqn8acAMrMNACTESOi/Z0Nxjzs3qlkKACIi1hoArgBm4ezqGpwWgcFhkey2Dk5scRgAvhgY2Ai0QSERUbIKgip6do4mrNzovPxVabXsAERebAYAdswA7gIwbZnoOaNAA==), we can see that the code gets lowered to:

```
public class Class
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
    {
        public string holder;

        internal void <Caller>b__0(string s)
        {
            this.holder = s;
        }

        internal void <Caller>g__SetHolder1(string s)
        {
            this.holder = s;
        }
    }

    public void Caller()
    {
        Class.<>c__DisplayClass0_0 @object = new Class.<>c__DisplayClass0_0();
        Action<string> setHolder = new Action<string>(@object.<Caller>b__0);
        this.DoStuff(setHolder);
        this.DoStuff(new Action<string>(@object.<Caller>g__SetHolder1));
    }

    public void DoStuff(Action<string> setHolder)
    {
        setHolder("holders new string");
    }
}
```

Because both `act` and `SetHolder` are closures over `holder`, when `Caller` is invoked a new closure class instance is created and new `Action` delegates are created for both the lambda and the local function. So the resultant code is identical for both.

Therefore, given the way you are using them here, it just comes down to readability (as many R# recommendations do). Local functions arguably have better syntax, so R# recommends you use it that way.

Comment: Your answer made me more curious as I had read [here](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/84/c-sharp-7-local-functions-are-funcs-too) that if a local function is static unless it accesses `this`, otherwise they are instance methods. I created an alternate example (see the next comment due to the link being too long for here) in sharplab.io (I didn't know about sharplab till now) which added some `null` checking around the `Action` but not the Local Function. Can you elaborate on the difference?

Comment: [Alternate example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACgoGYECY4DCcA3hnOQjlACyECGANgwKYBOAFAJQanoUKJcAHiQwAfHDoBjAC5wAvHADOCiUgCc7JZzR8KNOAGVmMgBIB7BsDbtRyzqoGbtushQAi5wzICuAMz92aRkdN3JPb39A4zNLa1ZQ9ABfDAxsBFoI3wDbQRFEcWUTCys2bnRefiViuJsAImAASyUABwY6AE84RoA7OClzHqVLZjrElOSgA===) using what equates to a `static Action` and Local Function.

Comment: I think I clicked why there is null checking. The `Action` is a variable and could be null, whereas the local function is, for lack of the correct terminology, a syntactical container for holding statements, therefore it doesn't need to be checked for null, as it is can't intrinsically be null.

Answer (score -1):

One of the benefits of local functions over delegates are that invoking them does not incur in a delegate instantiation and delegate invocation which is lost in your example because you are wrapping it with a delegate to pass it to `DoStuff`.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) to know all about **local functions**.